# Test functions that call promises inside of them with mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, mocha.js, middleware

I have a javascript function like this:

```
var otherModule = require('../otherModule');

function myFn(req, res, next) {

  otherModule.queryFunction()
    .then(function(results) {
      res.json(results);
    })
    .catch(function(err)) {
      res.json({
        err: err
      });
    });
}
```

In order to test `myFn` function I've mocked (with [mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery)) `otherModule.queryFunction` in my unit test so it returns some known results. In `myFn` unit test I want to test that `res.json` is being called. I know if I were testing `otherModule.queryFunction` I could accomplish that by returning the promise or by passing `done` argument to the spectation function. But i can't figure out how to make an asynchronous test if the asynchronous part is inside a function called by the function i'm testing.

I've tried this approach without success:

```
'use strict';
var chai = require('chai');
var mockery = require('mockery');
var expect = chai.expect;
var spies = require('chai-spies');
var myFn = require('path/to/myFn');
chai.use(spies);

describe('myFn tests', function (){

  var otherModule;
  var SOME_DATA = {data: 'hi'};
  beforeEach(function (){
    otherModule = {
      queryFunction: function queryFunctionMock(){
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          resolve(SOME_DATA);
        });

        return promise;
      }
    };
  });

  beforeEach(function (){
    mockery.enable({
      warnOnReplace: false,
      useCleanCache: true
    });

    mockery.registerMock('../otherModule', otherModule);
  });

  afterEach(function (){
    mockery.disable();
  });

  it('res.json should be called with otherModule.queryFunction results', function (){
    req = chai.spy();
    res = chai.spy.object(['json']);
    next = chai.spy();

    myFn(req, res, next);

    expect(res.json).to.have.been.called();    
  });
});
```

Comment: If your `myFn` is asynchronous, it should *`return` a promise*. Then you can easily hook on that in your tests.

Comment: I can't do that because myFn is an express middleware (http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) and it should'nt return anything.

Comment: Express doesn't really seem to care about the return value, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only thing wrong here, is that you need to move the require of your component under test, *after* you initialized mockery:

```
'use strict';
var chai = require('chai');
var mockery = require('mockery');
var expect = chai.expect;
var spies = require('chai-spies');
var myFn;
chai.use(spies);

describe('myFn tests', function (){

  // [...]

  beforeEach(function (){
    mockery.enable({
      warnOnReplace: false,
      useCleanCache: true
    });

    mockery.registerMock('../otherModule', otherModule);

    // now load the component:
    myFn = require('path/to/myFn');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It still doesn't work even if I require the Fn after mockery is enabled.

Comment: Thats weird. I created a project using your code and I receive the error  `ReferenceError: Promise is not defined`, which stems from the fact that there is no require for the promise library (I assume). But it shows that the mocking is successful. Are you getting any error?

Comment: You are rigth, it works. I ommited an importan point when converting my original use case to this example. I was redefining `otherModule.queryFunction` in some test in order to customize behavior. If I want to do this i should deregister and register de mock again because the mocked module isn't the same instance. Because of this mistake the end of the test was never reached as I expected.